# cv::repeat() data or header only?

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to do basic math operation on a couple of matrices.

In the beginning i was using a `cv::parallel_for_`

```cpp
cv::Mat A(307200, 100, CV_32F);
cv::Mat B(307200, 100, CV_32F);
cv::Mat C(307200, 1, CV_32F);

cv::parallel_for_(cv::Range(0,A.cols),[&](const cv::Range& range){
    for (int r = range.start; r < range.end; ++r) {
        B.col(r) = A.col(r) - C;
    }
});
```

By using `cv::repeat()` to adjust the sizes accordingly, i was able to speed it up quite a bit

```cpp
cv::Mat A(307200, 100, CV_32F);
cv::Mat B(307200, 100, CV_32F);
cv::Mat C(307200, 1, CV_32F);

cv::Mat D = cv::repeat(C,1,100)

cv::subtract(A,D,B);
```

In the [Docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga496c3860f3ac44c40b48811333cfda2d) it states that `cv::repeat()` copies the input array

> Fills the output array with repeated copies of the input array.

Is it actually copying the data or just the header?
In numpy there is [broadcast_to](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) which does not copy the data

> ... more than one element of a broadcasted array may refer to a single memory location.

Any way to replicate the with `opencv` only?

Could my code be sped up even further?

Comment: no, opencv's Mat type can't do these indexing tricks.